# Is it a bug in Mysqli - partial result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The mysqli prepare statement on execution return partial result only, ie. on fetch() $hash,$type hold their value but $userId stays empty, this problem appears only in prepared statement only.

```
if($statement=$this->db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`password`,`type` FROM `login` WHERE `username`=?")){
   $statement->bind_param("s",$username);
   if($statement->execute()){
     $statement->bind_result($userId,$hash,$type);
     if($statement->fetch()){
       if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
         $this->userId=$userId;
         if($type=='u')
            return true;
       }else {
         $this->error(11);
       }
     }else
       $this->error(5);
   }else
    $this->error(4);
 }else
   $this->error(3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved it by Casting id to CHAR

```
SELECT CAST(`id` AS CHAR),`password`,`type` FROM `login` WHERE `username`=?
```

but still not sure why it happened. Guess its bug with mysqli.